# Projection onto the set $\{x \geq 0: x_1 + \ldots + x_n \leq 1 \}$

Tags: projection, polyhedra, simplex, quadratic-programming

Is there an efficient algorithm to project a give point $y \in \mathbb{R}^n$ onto the set $S := \{x \in \mathbb{R}^n : x \geq 0, x_1 + \dots + x_n \leq 1 \}$?
In other words, can the minimum of $\| x - y\|_2^2$ with $x \in S$ can be found more efficiently than solving a quadratic program?

I've seen that there are efficient algorithms to project onto the probability simplex ($\Delta :=  \{x \in \mathbb{R}^n : x \geq 0, x_1 + \dots + x_n =1 \}$), as well as onto the $L_1$ unit ball (see e.g. http://machinelearning.org/archive/icml2008/papers/361.pdf). However, it seems to me that the problem above cannot be reduced to any of these.

Thank you very much!

Comment: Here's my gut feeling: Set every negative component of $y$ to zero, check whether the resulting vector lies in $S$.  If so, use that vector; if not, use the algorithm for the probability simplex on that vector.

Comment: Yes, that works! I was actually going to write the same just now. Please post it as an answer if you like.